# How to learn IP address of open server on same AWS security group

Tags: sockets, amazon-ec2, ip

I am running two EC instances.  They each run a python script and need to communicate, potentially using Python's SocketServer library.  How should the client 'learn' the server's ip address?  They are running in the same security group.

In the future I hope to launch ~100 of these client-server pairs, so I wasn't sure if elastic ip addresses were a good solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would definitely want the instances to communicate via the **private IP address**.

If the instances need to "discover" themselves, one option would be to **tag** the instances. An instance could then use an Amazon EC2 `DescribeInstances()` API call to find an instance with a particular tag. This will also provide the private IP address that can be used for communication.